# What happens when a the top level window closes but subframes do not?

Tags: javascript, dom

My understanding is that there is a single window object for JavaScript, which contains everything (document object, elements, etc...). I know that you can for example, click a button which runs the JS code `window.open()` to create a new window, and that window is a 'frame' inside the top level window object. My question is what happens when the top level window is closed, since the other windows that are opened don't get closed as well, does the top level window object change to one of the open windows?

Comment: `window.open` does not create a frame. It creates a new window, with a reference back to its `.opener`, which can be either closed (when closed before the opener) or detached (when the opener window is closed before).

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So they are all top level window objects in different instances?